# Store text as variable then change css style based on variable value

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have some simple HTML:

```
<div>Below is the div id containing the attorney value. </div>
<div id="attorney"> 0 </div>
<div id="profiletab1">THIS IS THE DIV I WANT TO HIDE</div>
```

On page load, when the value of div.attorney = '0' I'd like to change the `div.profiletab1` css `display style="none"`.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myfunc(){
   var atty= document.getElementById("attorney").value;
   if (atty=== '0'){
     document.getElementById("profiletab1").style.display = "none";
   }
 }
 window.onload = myfunc;
 </script>
```

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("attorney").textContent`, not `document.getElementById("attorney").value`. `value` is for `form` element's such as `input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the textContent, not the value and trim it since there are spaces in there:

```
function myfunc() {
    var atty = document.getElementById("attorney").textContent.trim();
    if (atty === '0') {
        document.getElementById("profiletab1").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` property is usually only kept on `input` elements. How about the `innerText`?

```
var atty= document.getElementById("attorney").value;
//                                           .innerText;
```

This text has spaces on either side, `0`, so it isn't equal to `0`. To trim the spacing you could use `String.prototype.trim()` like `atty.trim()` which would return `0`.

```
if (atty=== '0'){
//  atty.trim() === '0'
```

Is your "THIS IS THE DIV I WANT TO HIDE" the one with the ID "profiletab1"? That should work OK.

Put it together:

```
function myfunc(){
  var atty = document.getElementById("attorney").innerText;
  if (atty.trim() === '0') {
    document.getElementById("profiletab1").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use innerText instead of value. Value is for getting text in value=" " attribute.

```
<div>Below is the div id containing the attorney value. </div>
<div id="attorney">0</div>
<div id="profiletab1">THIS IS THE DIV I WANT TO HIDE</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc(){
    var atty = document.getElementById("attorney").innerText;
    if (atty=== '0')
    {
        document.getElementById("profiletab1").style.display = "none";
    }
}

window.onload = myfunc;
</script>
```